# python- re.findall how to separate content into groups

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need some clarification on how regex with the re.findall method works.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)')
content= ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, content))
```

So the above prints all the content that the pattern matches with the starting being: `\\[-16pt]` and the ending being '\ \n thinhline' plus all the text after it.
If I had the following content that matched by the pattern:

```
\\[-16pt]
x = 10
print ("hi")
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
y = 3
print ("bye")
\\
\thinhline
\\[-16pt]
z = 7
print ("zap")
\\
\thinhline
This is random text.
All of this is matched by re.findall, even though it is not included within the pattern.
xyz = "xyz"
```

How would I separate out each group so I could have, for example and be able to edit them independently:

group 1:

```
x = 10
print ("hi")
```

group 2:

```
y = 3
print ("bye")
```

group 3:

```
z = 7
print ("zap")
```

and none of the extra stuff that is matched after it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following runnable program:

```
import re

content="""\\[-16pt]
x = 10
print ("hi")
\\
thinhline
\\[-16pt]
y = 3
print ("bye")
\\
thinhline
\\[-16pt]
z = 7
print ("zap")
\\
thinhline
This is random text.
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)    # Start. Don't technically need to capture.
                         (.*?)             # What we want. Must capture ;)
                         (\n\\\nthinhline) # End. Also don't really need to capture
                      """, re.X | re.DOTALL)

for m in pattern.finditer(content):
    print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(2))
```

Output when run:

```
Matched:
----
x = 10
print ("hi")
----

Matched:
----
y = 3
print ("bye")
----

Matched:
----
z = 7
print ("zap")
----
```

Notes:

- By using the `re.X` option the expression can be multiline and commented
- By using the `re.DOTALL` option the excessive backslashes can be dropped
  and the "`.*?`" group (i.e. "get every character non-greedily up until the 
  next match") will include newlines.
- I used `finditer` rather than `findall` ... which technically moves away
  from your question, but you wanted to work with each match so I figured it
  was a good approach.
- I took the tab `\t` off the `thinhline` because I wasn't sure if it was
  meant to be a tab char or a backlash-then-t. Not that affects the above much
  but just wanted to be clear.
- I capture the start and end groups only for demonstration. Only the middle
  group is really needed.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. The actual piece of content I am using is much bigger and I have written the following function:
'def split(content):
   pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.*?)(\n\\\nthinhline)""", re.X | re.DOTALL)
   for m in pattern.finditer(content):
       print ("in for loop")
       print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(2))
   print ("in split")'
The program never goes within the loop. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Hmm, you'd have to post the full program, and comments aren't the best place, so perhaps start another question if you're still stuck. My 2c is to make sure the program is definitely calling the split function. You could put a breakpoint at the top of the function or use print statements, for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788201/python-re-compile-bug I have posted it here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what does (.*?) mean?  particularly what is the function of ? in the pattern. .* is any word.  What does the ? symbol do

Comment: The "." means "match any character" (except newline, kinda); the "*" means "zero or more". Those two together mean "match any character for any length." The "?" means "be non-greedy," which, to be more practical, means "match any character for any length but stop as soon as the pattern AFTER .*? matches."

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s=re.findall(r"(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)",test_str)
```

Findall returns a list of groups matched.

Here `s` is a list.You can access what you want by referring `s[0]` or `s[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

use re.findall

```
pattern=r"""(\\\[-16pt])(\n[a-z]+\s+\={1}\s+[0-9]+)(\nprint\s+\({1}\"[a-z]+\"\){1})\n(\\\nthinhline)\n"""
result=re.findall(pattern,content)
count=1
for item in result:
    print("row",count,item[2])
    count+=1
```

output:

```
row 1 
print ("hi")
row 2 
print ("bye")
row 3 
print ("zap")
```