# re.compile not matching my string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Here is my code:

```
def split(content):
   pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.*?)(\n\\\nthinhline)""", re.X | re.DOTALL)
   print(pattern.finditer(content))
   for m in pattern.finditer(content):
       print ("in for loop")
       print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(2))
   print ("in split")


def replacement(content):
   split(content)
   pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)')
   content= ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, content))
   print ("in replace")
   return content
```

Here is the output:

```
<callable-iterator object at 0x2ab2e09cfe10>
in split
in replace
```

I have tried the algorithm with a different string and it works fine. I have also tested to see if content is a string and it is. Why isn't the program going into the for..loop even though it is going into split()?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm 100% sure there's no bug in `re.compile`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745894/python-re-findall-how-to-separate-content-into-groups/27746133?noredirect=1#comment43910795_27746133 This is what I am trying to do, but with a much larger piece of text.

Comment: What happens if you remove `print(pattern.finditer(content))`?

Comment: Your string is simply not matching. The "print('in split')" is outside the loop...

Comment: It would additionally help if you post a full, runnable program that shows the problem. I did this in my answer to your original question. You don't have to post *the real* full runnable program, but you could cut it down with real input (though smaller than the full input) and main, so we can copy/paste/run it to see your problem. Often, working through this helps reveal the problem to you.

Answer (score 1):

See comments:

```
def split(content):
   pattern = re.compile(r"""(\\\[-16pt]\n)(.*?)(\n\\\nthinhline)""", re.X | re.DOTALL)

   # the message you're seeing is correct - this line prints an iterator object -
   # like all iterators, you must actually iterate over it to see the iterator's
   # contents. You're seeing the string representation of an iterator, not the
   # iterator's contents.
   print(pattern.finditer(content))

   # this will iterate over the match objects in the iterator object - but there
   # is no guarantee that any exist
   for m in pattern.finditer(content):
       print ("in for loop")
       print("Matched:\n----\n%s\n----\n" % m.group(2))

   # now you're printing this string, which you correctly observed - note that it is
   # outside of the for loop. This means that its execution is not dependent on the 
   # regex actually finding any matches.
   print ("in split")
```

Since "in for loop" was never printed, that means that your regex never matched. I've had good success using the [Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/) website to debug my regexes. Try using that website on some sample text to make sure your regex actually matches where you expect it to.

Your current problem is simply that your regex isn't finding any matches.

Comment: @mbomb007 Oooh... I haven't seen that site before. I like it too.